# How to use pivot in SQL Server to make a table like this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, azure-sql-database

So let's say I have a table like this

| Code | Name | Budget |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | ABC | 1500 |
| 1111 | DEF | 2000 |
| 1111 | QWE | 3000 |
| 2222 | ABC | 1800 |
| 2222 | DEF | 1000 |
| 3333 | QWE | 1500 |

How can I display the results this way? I know you can use PIVOT but I don't understand how to build the sentence.

| Code | ABC | DEF | QWE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 1500 | 2000 | 3000 |
| 2222 | 1800 | 1000 | 0 |
| 3333 | 0 | 0 | 1500 |

I tried using different PIVOT examples but couldn't get one structured the same way as my data

EDIT: There will be many more codes, and could also have many more names other than ABC, DEF & QWE

Comment: Will you *only* have the names `'ABC',`'DEF', and `'QWE'`?

Comment: If `PIVOT` feels a bit difficult, try using the `CASE` + aggregation way. Efficiency of both two is almost identical, 2nd one is just more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using Pivot and dynamic query together:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

        ,@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @cols = STUFF((
                SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[Name])
                FROM (
                    SELECT DISTINCT [Name]
                    FROM Budget
                    ) c
                ORDER BY [Name]
                FOR XML PATH('')
                    ,TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

                SELECT @cols


                SET @query = N'SELECT *
from
(SELECT Code,Name,Budget FROM budget )
AS source
PIVOT
(
 sum(Budget) 
  FOR [Name] IN ( '+@cols+')
)AS PivotTable
';

EXECUTE (@query)
```